# ASP.NET VB How to add value from one column into multiple series of line chart

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, charts

I want to ask about line chart series in vb.net. I have a line chart that has two series. I want to add data into each series from the same column database with a condition.

my table in the database:

```
 Date#####   |  Value1 |  Value2 |   Value3 | Type
 23/04/2014  |  1,2    |    12,3 |    10    | Green
 23/04/2014  |  11,2   |    3    |   10,3   | Non-Green    
 24/04/2014  |  10,9   |    3    |    11    | Green
 24/04/2014  |  2,3    |    12,3 |    8     | Green
 25/04/2014  |  10     |    2    |   10,8   | Non-Green    
 25/04/2014  |  1,4    |    5    |    12    | Green
```

I have this table after executing my query on the code from database :

```
  Date#####  | Count |Type
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Green
 23/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 24/04/2014  |  3    | Green
 25/04/2014  |  2    | Non-Green
 25/04/2014  |  1    | Green
```

I would like to add the Greentype data into series 1, and the non-Green into series 2 for each group of date. the date will become x Axis,, and the value of data in green type will become a data for y Axis in series1, and non green in series2.
I only able to take one of the type,, for example I take green type data... Here is my code :

`Protected Sub Chart3Date10_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Chart3Date10.Load
Dim sqlProducts As String = "SELECT d, cnt FROM(SELECT TOP 7 [date] AS d, SUM(CASE WHEN Value1 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value2 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Value3 >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt FROM tbBooth where Type = 'Green' GROUP BY [date],[Type] ORDER BY [date] DESC) x ORDER BY d ASC"
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlProducts, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "tbBooth")`

```
    Dim ChartArea1 As ChartArea = New ChartArea()
    Dim Legend1 As Legend = New Legend()
    Dim Series1 As Series = New Series()

    Series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea"
    Chart3Date10.TabIndex = 0
    Chart3Date10.Series("Series1").XValueMember = "d"
    Chart3Date10.Series("Series1").YValueMembers = "cnt"
    ' Chart3Date10.Series("Series2").YValueMembers = ""  ''' Don't know how to call the nongreen type
    Chart3Date10.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = "7"
    Chart3Date10.DataSource = ds.Tables("tbBooth")
    Chart3Date10.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = False
    Chart3Date10.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45
    With Chart3Date10.Series(0)
        .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        .BorderWidth = 4
        .BackSecondaryColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        .BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
        .MarkerStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Triangle
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .MarkerColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255)
        .MarkerBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255)
        .Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255)
    End With
    With Chart3Date10.Series(1)
        '.Points.DataBind(dtGraph.DefaultView, "Column1", "Column2", Nothing)
        .ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line
        .BorderWidth = 4
        .BackSecondaryColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        .BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
        .MarkerStyle = DataVisualization.Charting.MarkerStyle.Square
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .MarkerColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255)
        .MarkerBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255)
        .Color = Color.FromArgb(30, 144, 255) 'change the color of line
    End With
End Sub
```

Is there anyway how to do it?
Should I use loop to do that?

Thanks in advance...